# How to propagate opentelemetry span context to http request headers in B3 format?

Tags: python, b3

Our organization uses a few different tracing mechanisms. The prominent one is B3. But some services also use Datadog. For the purpose of this question, I am mainly concerned with B3.

I dont want to take dependency on any specific vendor. So I imported `opentelemetry` python sdk.

Now, I want to propogate the span to a HTTP service call in B3 format.

How do I do that? I searched and found `py-zipkin` which unfortunately, is an `opentracing` compatible lib, not `opentelemetry`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... Googling properly reveals that a propagator for `B3` already exists.

[opentelemetry-propagator-b3](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/tree/main/propagator/opentelemetry-propagator-b3)